# flask wtform field data disappearingappend_entry

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Please help - does flask/wtforms somehow treat the data property of a field differently after an append_entry call or am I just really doing this wrong?

I have a form that gets its data from a yaml file.  On the initial GET request, the form populates showing the icons from the `{% if ifc.poe.data %}` as expected.  If either button is hit to add a module or interface, the POST re-renders the page, but now ifc.poe.data is empty and thus no icons are rendered.  If you comment out the `if ifc.xxx.data` portion and uncomment out the actual fields, the fields are rendered with the proper data every time.  Is this something with how I'm building the form class or in how I'm handling the POST?  What happened to the ifc.xxx.data?

Any help is appreciated, I'm pretty new at this.

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import Form      
from wtforms import Form as wtfForm # Bad hack to get around csrf in fieldlist  
class DevInterface(wtfForm):
    e_regex = '^ae(\d+)$'
    ifc = StringField("Interface", validators=[DataRequired()])
    poe = BooleanField('PoE', validators=[Optional()], default=False)
    uplink = BooleanField('Uplink', validators=[Optional()],default=False)
    desc = StringField("Description", validators=[Optional()],default='')
    voip = StringField("VOIP", validators=[Optional()], default='')
    etheropt = StringField("LAG interface", validators=[Optional(),Regexp(e_regex, message='Must designate an ae interface, eg. ae4')])
class DevHardware(wtfForm):
    module = SelectField('Module', choices=[
                  ('ex2200-24p','ex2200-24p'),('ex2200-48p','ex2200-48p'),
                  ('ex4200-10g','ex4200-10g'),('ex4200-24f','ex4200-24f')],
                  default='ex2200-48p')
fpc = SelectField('FPC', choices=[(str(i),str(i)) for i in range(10)], default=0)

class DevOptions():  
    id = StringField('Device Serial Number', validators=[DataRequired()])  
    hostname = StringField('Hostname', validators=[DataRequired()])  
    make = SelectField('Make', choices=[('juniper','Juniper')], default = 'juniper')  

class AddDev(Form, DevOptions):
    modules = FieldList(FormField(DevHardware), min_entries=1)
    interfaces = FieldList(FormField(DevInterface), min_entries=1)
    add_ifc = SubmitField()
    add_module = SubmitField()
```

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/editdev/<vspc>/<dev>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def editdev(vspc,dev):
    from skynet.forms import AddDev
try:
    d = s.loaddev(dev)
except IOError as e:
    flash(dev + ' does not exist.', category='danger')
    return redirect(url_for('editvspc', vspc=vspc))

# Have to change up how the data is presented for the form
d['id'] = dev
ifcs = d['interfaces']
del d['interfaces']
l = []
for i in ifcs:
    j={}
    j['ifc'] = i
    j.update(ifcs[i])
    l.append(j)
d['interfaces'] = sorted(l, key=lambda k: k['ifc'])

form = AddDev(request.form, data=d)

if form.add_ifc.data:
    form.interfaces.append_entry()
elif form.add_module.data:
    form.modules.append_entry()
elif request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    # Placeholder for now
    print 'Updated device'
for error in form.errors:
    for e in form[error].errors:
        flash(e, category='danger')
return render_template('adddev.html', form=form)
```

**template**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}  
{% import "bootstrap/utils.html" as util %}
{% block content %}
{{ super() }}
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 align='center'>Add Device</h1>
      <form method="post" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="form-group">
          <table class="table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{{ form.id.label }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.id(size=20) }}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>{{ form.hostname.label }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.hostname(size=20) }}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>{{ form.make.label }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.make}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          {{ form.add_module }}
          <table class="table">
            <tbody>
              {% for field in form.modules.entries %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{ field.module.label }}</td>
                <td>{{ field.module }}</td>
                <td>{{ field.fpc.label }}</td>
                <td>{{ field.fpc }}</td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Interface</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>PoE</th>
                <th>VoIP</th>
                <th>LAG</th>
                <th>Uplink</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody>
          {% for ifc in form.interfaces %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ ifc.ifc(size=10) }}</td>
              <td>{{ ifc.desc }}</td>
              <td>
                {% if ifc.poe.data %}
                {{ util.icon('flash', style='color:red') }}
                {% endif %}
                {% if ifc.voip.data %}
                {{ util.icon('phone-alt', style='color:green') }}
                {% endif %}
                {% if ifc.etheropt.data %}
                <a class="label label-success">{{ ifc.etheropt.data }}</a>
                {% endif %}
                {% if ifc.uplink.data %}
                {{ util.icon('open', style='color:blue') }}
                {% endif %}
              </td>
           {# <td>{{ ifc.poe }}</td>
              <td>{{ ifc.voip }}</td>
              <td>{{ ifc.etheropt }}</td>
              <td>{{ ifc.uplink }}</td> #}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
          {{ form.add_ifc }}
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Device</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```